# retrive session attribute and sort it into String

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

hello I successfully get the logged in username value from servelt into JSP page as below:

```
Welcome:${loginedUser.userName}
```

I need to use this username in If condition in JSP page to compare with another value like for example:

```
<%if(tc.getTEAssigned().equalsIgnoreCase(${loginedUser.userName}) %>
```

set Attribute:

```
    // Store user info in Session.
public static void storeLoginedUser(HttpSession session, UserAccount loginedUser) {
    // On the JSP can access via ${loginedUser}
    session.setAttribute("loginedUser", loginedUser);        
}
```

UserAccount contains those values:

```
   private String userName;
   private String gender;
   private String password;
   private List<String> roles;
```

i tried to use

```
 <%=session.getAttribute("loginedUser") %>
```

but it result is

```
com.jdbc.UserAccount@2990e7ee
```

so my question is how to use ${loginedUser.userName}  value in If conditions

Comment: already data passed from Servelt to JSP and printed successfully in GUI also but now i need to use this data into JSP in if condition as this user can view this page but i need to validate if he can make any action on it or just view without taking any action

Comment: then please define your question more specifically. What you have? what you want to achieve? and name the title accordingly.

Comment: Just get that data using `request.getAttribute("something")` and then use in your `if` condition .

Comment: Giorgi: Questions updated

Comment: Swati: i used <%=session.getAttribute("loginedUser") %> but it value is "com.jdbc.UserAccount@2990e7ee" noting that logiendUser contains more than value like "username, Password and roles"

Comment: You can do like this `UserAccount sb=(UserAccount)request.getAttribute("loginedUser");` and then access username value using getter method i.e :`sb.getUsername()`